# What is the reason my byte array is full of zeros after converting a file which have text init?

Tags: java, file-io, byte

I am trying read a text file and insert those content into database. 
My file.length() is 3540
But the byte array is full of zeros. As a result when I open the text file, it is empty.

```
File file = new File("/temp/abc.txt");
byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()]; 
databaseBean.setContentInByteArray(bytesArray);
```

Here the byteArray is full of zeroes.

Comment: Please show us some code to help us understand

Comment: The short answer is that your code is not opening and reading the file.   See the linked Q&A for ways to read a file into a byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Path file = Paths.get("/temp/abc.txt");
byte[] bytesArray = Files.readAllBytes(path); 
databaseBean.setContentInByteArray(bytesArray);
```

A `File` is just a holder for a physical file on disk, a path, not its content.

`new byte[42]` will create a zeroed array of 42 bytes.

You would have to read those bytes. `Path` is a newer, more general class i.o. `File` and I used the [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class to read all those bytes.